# Get coefficient of a symbolized symbol in a sum that involves other symbolized expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, symbols, coefficients

My mathematica notebook begins with symbolizing all expressions of the form $x$ subscript an integer, "$x_k$",

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "_"]]]
```

I then define a polynomial in terms of these symbols, eg.

$$p = x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5 - 2x_1 + x_1^2$$

Now I would like to obtain the coefficient of say $x_1$. (I.e. for this example this would be $2$.) The command `Coefficient[p, x_1]`  does not work because it treats all the other symbols as scalars, i.e. I get $x_2x_3$ as part of the answer.

Given this setup how can I obtain the coefficient of monomials like $x_1$ or $x_2x_3$ in the usual way?

Edit: the way `p` was coded is:

```
toVariableSymbol[i_] := Subscript["x", i];
vars = Map[toVariableSymbol, Range[n]];
pairwiseProducts = Total[Flatten[
   Table[Subscript["x", i]*Subscript["x", j], {i, 1, n}, {j, i, n}]]];
p = Total[vars] - pairwiseProducts - x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5;
```

Comment: would it be possible to give us how you coded `p` in your notebook? many thanks in advance!

Comment: @bmf I just edited it. This is just part of it but I think this should describe it well enough. There are some other degree 3 terms but that's all manually typed up for now.

Comment: `n` is left undefined in your post. Am I correct to assume that `n=5`?

Comment: @bmf The reason why I didn't specify it, is because later on I would like to be able able to change the value of `n`, so I'd ideally like to find a solution that's general enough that it doesn't depend on the number of x_1's my polynomial involves... To answer your question, I actually have `n=6` for now.

Comment: thanks for that. I just pointed it out because if it is left undefined `Mathematica` complains. I copied the code you provided and used `n=6`. As you can see in this [`screenshot`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFkSu.png) there's an issue... I am on `V13.0.0`

Comment: @bmf I think it's probably the last, degree 5 term. It is non-essential I added it here to make sure it doesn't seem like the highest degree term is quadratic. The way I type the degree 5 monomial is by hitting Ctrl + Underscore to type in a subscript. With that for me it evaluates fine, https://imgur.com/a/yIN7TF3

Comment: thanks. I just wrote something, so you might want to have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CoefficientArrays`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html)

I am doing the example given in the OP:

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "_"]]]

p = Subscript["x", 1] Subscript["x", 2] Subscript["x", 3] + 
  Subscript["x", 4] Subscript["x", 5] - 2 Subscript["x", 1] + 
  Subscript["x", 1]^2
```

> [image: ppoly]

```
Normal@CoefficientArrays[p]
```

> [image: coefarrays]

Another approach would be to use [`MonomialList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList.html)

```
MonomialList[p]
```

> [image: monomials]

**Edit: perhaps closer to what the author of the OP had in mind**

```
Coefficient[p, Subscript["x", 1]]
```

> [image: coef]

and perhaps cleaner is to do

```
Coefficient[MonomialList[p], Subscript["x", 1]]
```

> [image: coefmono]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I'll try to make it work. `MonomialList` looks very useful.

Comment: @gen glad I was able to help :). These should work on longer polynomials as well. For `CoefficientArrays` I suggest that you read the documentation first and then use the [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) command to extract specific terms

Comment: @gen since you mentioned the command [`Coefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html) in the OP I managed to extract it using that command. you might want to have a look at the updated version

Comment: Yes, I like this one most. I have one finally question though: The last photo in your answer shows the result given by your code, `{0, x_2 x_3, -2, 0}`. Now I would like to extract -2 from this somehow. I tried filtering the array by `Select[arr, _Real]` but that didn't work... Can you think of a way of throwing away all entries of this list that involve an `x_i`?

Comment: @gen this is why I suggested the `Part` command earlier. I guess you want something like `{0, x_ 2 x_ 3, -2, 0}[[3]]` if I understood correctly, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like but in a programmable way of course, because I don't know the index of the **unique non-zero number** in that list.

Comment: @gen Yes, this makes sense. So if you try `array = {0, Subscript["x", 2] Subscript["x", 3], -2, 0}` and then `Union[array /. x_*n_ :> 0]` is this better? Or do you want to delete the `0` as well?

Comment: @gen in case you want the `0` deleted try `Union[array /. x_*n_ :> 0] // DeleteCases[#, 0, Infinity] &`

Comment: Oh my, yes that's perfect. The zero doesn't matter, because I can call a `Total` on the output after I filtered all the variables `x_i` away... I think this is a fully functioning solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: @gen glad I was able to help. Thanks for the accept :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135618/discussion-between-gen-and-bmf).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the following preserves the order of the monomials in the polynomial:

[image]

Considering the previous observation, we can define the following function:

```
MyCoefficient[expr_?PolynomialQ, var_, position_Integer] := 
 Total[Take[Thread[Level[expr, {1}] -> Map[Total, CoefficientList[Level[expr, {1}], var]]][[All, -1]], {position}]]
```

Testing the function:

```
MyCoefficient[p, Subscript[x, 1], #] & /@ Range[4]
(*{-2, 1, Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4] Subscript[x, 5]}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
coef[p_, term_] := With[{powers = FirstPosition[CoefficientList[term, Variables[{p, term}]], 1]},
                    CoefficientList[p, Variables[{p, term}], powers][[Sequence @@ powers]]]
coef[x1 x2 + 3 x1 + 2 x2 + 4 x3 x2^5 + 2 x2 x3, x3 x2]
(* 2 *)
```

However, if `p` contains symbolic constants you would have to replace both of the `Variables[p]` by a manually set list like `{x1, x2, x3}`.

Comment: I tried to make it work the way you suggested, but something doesn't seem to work: https://imgur.com/a/7fRhrYk