# Issue with symbolizing all expressions of the form $x_k$ following recent update

Tags: symbolic

A [notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266921/get-coefficient-of-a-symbolized-symbol-in-a-sum-that-involves-other-symbolized-e) that I created a while ago starts with the following two lines:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x","_"]]];
```

I need this so that I can treat $x_1, x_2, ...$ as symbols when I deal with multilinear polynomials. Eg. $x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_4 x_5 + 1$.

My notebook used to work fine until some recent updates. Currently, these two lines trigger a number of errors:

[image]

How can I fix this? With my older local installation (as opposed to Wolfram Cloud) there are no issues with these lines.